# Debian Wheezy Archive EOL Term

Tags: debian, archive

Debian Wheezy has reached its EOL (end of life) now. Does it also mean that all its files found here http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy/ will be killed and deleted for good one day too? How long are the archives kept for and do they also have this EOL term?

Answer (score 7):

EOL means that the distribution no longer receives any updates. The files on archive.debian.org won’t disappear any time soon — most of Debian’s historical releases are [still available there](http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/); see [the README file](http://archive.debian.org/README) for details.

I’m not aware of any specific “official” declaration in this regard, but as far as I’m aware distributions moved to the archive are never deleted, and the archive is supposed to live at least as long as the Debian project.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Appreciate. I read their entire README file but I didn't find any answers / information on how long will the archives be kept for? Is it forever? 10 years? 2 years after EOL?

Comment: Probably "as long as the Debian Project exists and can keep the server maintained", given that even Debian 1.3 "bo" from year 1997 is still there, more than 20 years later.

Comment: AFAIK, for the lifetime of the Debian project, if not longer.

Comment: That's great! Thank you, guys. If they keep something from 1997 and it is still there then I think it's for life.

Comment: @Dennis: This should be accepted as an answer.